# NSIS Script - Check the existence of fonts and register the Custom fonts

Tags: fonts, exe, nsis, truetype

I am new to the implementation of NSIS where i would like to create a windows installer file such that it installs custom fonts to "C:\Windows\Fonts" during the installation process.

I am using the following code to copy the custom fonts to the Windows Fonts directory. The files are not getting copied to that location

```
  ; Install the fonts
    Section
        ; Loop through all the fonts in the current directory
        !ForEachFile `*.ttf` Font
            ; Check if the font does not already exist in the font directory
            IfFileNotExists $FONT_DIR\$Font InstallFont
        NextFile
    SectionEnd

; The "InstallFont" function installs a font
Function InstallFont
    ; Copy the font file to the font directory
    CopyFiles $Font $FONT_DIR
    ; Register the font with Windows
    FontName::InstallFont $Font
FunctionEnd
```

Even i have tried the following script but still it didnt install the fonts to Windows fonts directory

```
Section "Fonts"
  StrCpy $FONT_DIR $FONTS

  !insertmacro InstallTTFFont 'font1.ttf'
  !insertmacro InstallTTFFont 'font2.ttf'
  !insertmacro InstallTTFFont 'font3.ttf'
  !insertmacro InstallTTFFont 'font4.ttf'

  SendMessage ${HWND_BROADCAST} ${WM_FONTCHANGE} 0 0 /TIMEOUT=5000
SectionEnd
```

I have Provided the custom fonts directory path to $FONT_DIR i.e C:\Users\user\Documents\NSIS\FontsInstallerSetup\Fonts.

Can you please suggest the process that checks the existence of fonts and then install the fonts using NSIS?

Comment: No example code? What fails with file not found?

Comment: What is ForEachFile ?

Comment: @Anders Yes.. It does not exist.. I found that piece of code from other source and implemented it.. Can you please provide me the script for looping through custom fonts directory and install fonts onto my machine

Answer (score 0):

Grab [FontInstall.nsh](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Installing_fonts) and the [FontInfo plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/FontInfo_plug-in).

```
RequestExecutionLevel Admin
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include FontInstall.nsh

Section
InitPluginsDir
SetOutPath $PluginsDir
File /r "C:\Users\user\Documents\NSIS\FontsInstallerSetup\Fonts\*.ttf" ; Folder with your fonts
SetOutPath $Fonts
FindFirst $1 $2 $PluginsDir\*.ttf
loop:
    StrCmp $2 "" done
    FontInfo::GetFontName "$PluginsDir\$2"
    ${If} $0 != ""
        DetailPrint "Installing $0 ($2)..."
        CopyFiles /SILENT /FILESONLY "$PluginsDir\$2" $Fonts
        !insertmacro FontInstallTTF "" "$2" $0
    ${EndIf}
    FindNext $1 $2
    Goto loop
done:
FindClose $1
SendMessage ${HWND_BROADCAST} ${WM_FONTCHANGE} 0 0 /TIMEOUT=5000
SectionEnd
```

(I did not test this but it should be pretty close)